# Moving text using setTimeout in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm doing a tutorial and the text "Yoo" is suppose to move right but it doesn't. Ty

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var timer, x_pos=0, txt;
    function _timer() {
        txt = document.getElementById("txt");
        x_pos = x_pos+1;
        txt.style.left = x;
        timer = setTimeout(_timer, 50);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="_timer()">
<h1 id="txt" style="position:absolute; left:0"> Yooo </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change txt.style.left = x; to txt.style.left = x_pos;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable x is never defined and you should provide the `left` in `px` as

```
txt.style.left = x_pos + "px";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var timer, x_pos=0, txt;
    function _timer() {
        txt = document.getElementById("txt");
        x_pos = x_pos+1;
        txt.style.left = x_pos + "px";
        timer = setTimeout(_timer, 50);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="_timer()">
<h1 id="txt" style="position:absolute; left:0"> Yooo </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable x is never defined. Try:

```
txt.style.left = x_pos;
```

instead of

```
txt.style.left = x;
```

So that your final code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var timer, x_pos=0, txt;
    function _timer() {
        txt = document.getElementById("txt");
        x_pos = x_pos+1;
        txt.style.left = x_pos;
        timer = setTimeout(_timer, 50);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="_timer()">
<h1 id="txt" style="position:absolute; left:0"> Yooo </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes i missed that when i was changing up variables thought x might be some special variable, i missed 'px' but yes thank you need to fix that too

Answer (score 0):

you had forget add unit :)

```
txt.style.left = x+'px';
```